# Passing lambda as template parameter to templated by function-pointer function

Tags: templates, c++11, lambda, c++14, c++17

Looks like I cannot pass a no-capture lambda as a template parameter to a templated by function-pointer function. Am I doing it the wrong way, or is it impossible?

```
#include <iostream>

// Function templated by function pointer
template< void(*F)(int) >
void fun( int i )
{
    F(i);
}

void f1( int i )
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    void(*f2)( int ) = []( int i ) { std::cout << i << std::endl; };

    fun<f1>( 42 ); // THIS WORKS
    f2( 42 );      // THIS WORKS
    fun<f2>( 42 ); // THIS DOES NOT WORK (COMPILE-TIME ERROR) !!!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::function`.

Comment: f2 is a variable - runtime parameter. Templates require build time parameters (constants and types). Try adding const, but it probably won't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's mostly a problem in the language's definition, the following makes it more obvious:

```
using F2 = void(*)( int );

// this works:
constexpr F2 f2 = f1;

// this does not:
constexpr F2 f2 = []( int i ) { std::cout << i << std::endl; };
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/738eb6e8dc29d6e5)

This basically means that your hope/expectation is quite reasonable, but the language is currently not defined that way - a lambda does not yield a function pointer which is suitable as a `constexpr`.

There is, however, a proposal to fix this issue: [N4487](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

This is not viable because `f2` is not `constexpr` (i.e., is a runtime variable). As such it cannot be used as a template parameter. You could alter your code and make it more generic in the following manner:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void fun(F f, Args... args) {
  f(args...);
}

void f1( int i ) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto f2 = []( int i ) { std::cout << i << std::endl; };
    fun(f1, 42);
    f2( 42 );
    fun(f2, 42 );
    return 0;
}
```