# Cannot use template function with lambda as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have got template function with function pointer as a template parameter. When I use global function pointer as template parameters everything works fine. When I try to define function locally using lambda(without capturing) problems arise.
Here is minimal code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<double (*f)(double, double)>
std::vector<double> calculate(std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& y){
    std::vector<double> z(x.size());
    std::transform(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin(),z.begin(),f);
    return z;
}

double calc(double n, double k){
    return n*n+k*k;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double (*fun)(double,double) = [](double n, double k){return n*n+k*k;};
    std::vector<double> x(5,3);
    std::vector<double> y(5,4);
    std::vector<double> z1 = calculate<&calc>(x,y);//it works fine
    std::vector<double> z2 = calculate<fun>(x,y);//this line gives a bunch of errors

    for(int i=0;i<z1.size();i++){
        std::cout<<z1[i]<<" ";
    }
    for(int i=0;i<z2.size();i++){
        std::cout<<z2[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is errors:

1. `the value of 'fun' is not usable in a constant expression`
2. `no matching function for call to 'calculate(std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&)`
3. `'fun' is not a valid template argument for type 'double (*)(double, double)'`
4. `it must be the address of a function with external linkage`

Comment: Lambas have an unspecified type; either use `auto` or `std::function` to store them.

Comment: AFAICT, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420085/is-constexpr-supported-with-lambda-functions-expressions. The 'fun' is a variable and as such cannot be used as a template parameter.

Comment: @MatsKindahl Seems closer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849059/lambda-expressions-as-class-template-parameters?rq=1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing lambda as template parameter to templated by function-pointer function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031999/passing-lambda-as-template-parameter-to-templated-by-function-pointer-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calc` is a constant and can be used as a template parameter, while instead `fun` is a variable and therefore cannot.

Unfortunately you cannot pass a lambda directly as a template parameter just because you cannot (the standard says you cannot)... so the following is **not** going to work:

```
calculate<[](double n, double k){ return n*n+k*k; }>(x, y);
```

In you specific case however it's not clear why the function is a template parameter and not just a parameter... (in that case passing `fun` would work fine).

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass pointer to functions as template arguments if they're `constexpr`.
In this case however:

```
double (*fun)(double,double) = [](double n, double k){return n*n+k*k;};
```

`fun` is not, thus you cannot pass it as a template argument.

In simple words `fun` is runtime variable and you cannot pass a runtime variable as template argument.

Comment: function `calc` is not `constexpr`.Why  can I use it as template parameter?

Comment: And unfortunately you cannot pass a lambda either with `calculate<[](double n, double k){ return n*n+k*k; }>(x, y)` even if that would be constant (just because you cannot).

Comment: @lnk I'm not talking about `constexpr` functions. `fun` is not a constant expression.